# Desenvolvimento de uma cantina C++

Tags: c++

Tenho um projeto da universidade que me foi pedido para criar uma cantina, no qual foi pedido para criar grupos de alunos / staff para adicionar à fila de espera. Os grupos podem ter 1 a 10 membros . O problema aqui é conseguir conseguir gerar esses grupos.
Os alunos são definidos pelo seu primeiro nome , ultimo nome, numero de aluno, numero de grupo, plafond e curso;
O staff é definido pelo seu primeiro nome, ultimo nome , numero de departamento, numero de funcionario e plafond;
Grupos só podem conter alunos ou staff, não os dois misturados.

Criei as seguintes structs:

```
struct identidade {
struct aluno {
    string primeironome;
    string ultimonome;
    int numero;
    string curso;
    float plafond;

};
struct staff {
    string primeironome;
    string ultimonome;
    int numero;
    float plafond;
};
```

};
struct grupo {
    int numerogrupo;
    identidade * pessoas;
};

mas aqui o problema é como criar os grupos, desenvolvi a seguinte função ( fiz só para alunos , por enquanto)

os nomes das identidades tem de ser escolhidos de forma aleatorio e os cursos tambem.

```
void criagrupo(grupo * listaespera, string * pNome, string * uNome, string * cursos) {
int i = rand() % 43; // serve para percorrer os arrays com primeiros nomes
int j = rand() % 96; // serve para percorrer os arrays com ultimos nomes
int k = rand() % 18; // server para percorrer os arrays com os cursos
int tamanho = rand() % 10 + 1;
int dinheiro = rand() % 100 + 1;
int numero = rand() % 20 + 1;
grupo * novogrupo = new grupo;
novogrupo->numerogrupo = numero;
identidade * quantidade = new identidade[tamanho];
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    identidade::aluno * aluno = new identidade::aluno();
    aluno->primeironome = pNome[i];
    aluno->ultimonome = uNome[j];
    aluno->curso = cursos[k];
    aluno->plafond = dinheiro;
    quantidade[i] = aluno;

};
```

a função ainda não está acabada mas ocorre me um erro no quantidade[i] = aluno, ao qual não estou a conseguir resolver. Agradecia quem pudesse ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos la, está ocorrendo erro pois os tipos das variáveis são diferentes. Quantidade é uma variável do tipo **identidade*** e aluno é uma variável **identidade::aluno***. Mesmo que na declaração você tenha colocado uma na outra, são variáveis diferentes.

você tem várias formas de corrigir esse erro. Alterar a declaração da quantidade para:

```
identidade::aluno * quantidade = new identidade::aluno[tamanho];
```

ou alterar a struct para incluir a variável aluno:

```
struct identidade {
    struct aluno {
        string primeironome;
        string ultimonome;
        int numero;
        string curso;
        float plafond;

    };
    struct staff {
        string primeironome;
        string ultimonome;
        int numero;
        float plafond;
    };

    aluno *alunoExemplo;
}
```

desta forma você pode acessar o aluno assim:

```
quantidade[i].alunoExemplo = aluno
```

Desta forma cada variavel **identidade** tem um ponteiros, um para **aluno**.

Outra forma seria você implementar herança usando classes. Mas não sei em que nível de aprendizado você está. Não sei se você precisa necessariamente utilizar C ( não acredito que seja pois você utilizou string, que não tem em C.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/